# php foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I have two arrays in my code.
Need to perform a foreach loop on both of these arrays at one time. Is it possible to supply two arguments at the same time such as `foreach($array1 as $data1 and $array2 as $data2)`
or something else?

Comment: Why do you need to loop both arrays at the same time?

Comment: Will they have the same number of elements?

Answer (score 2):

If they both the same keys, you can do this:

```
foreach($array1 as $key=>data1){
    $data2 = $array2[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming both have the same number of elements

If they both are 0-indexed arrays:

```
foreach ($array_1 as $key => $data_1) {
  $data_2 = $array_2[$key];
}
```

Otherwise:

```
$keys = array_combine(array_keys($array_1), array_keys($array_2));

foreach ($keys as $key_1 => $key_2) {
  $data_1 = $array_1[$key_1];
  $data_2 = $array_2[$key_2];
}
```

Comment: nice solution with the keys mapping, +1

Answer (score 1):

Dont use a foreach. use a For, and use the incremented index, eg. $i++ to access both arrays at once.

Are both arrays the same size always?
Then this will work:

```
$max =sizeof($array);
for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++)

array[$i].attribute
array2[$i].attribute
```

If the arrays are different sizes, you may have to tweak your approach. Possibly use a while.

iterative methods:

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php

Comment: never use a function inside a for condition, it will execute it each loop, your example should be instead : for ($i = 0, $max = sizeof($array); $i < $max; $i++)

Comment: That's what the `for` loop is for. I would add the `{...}`, so one can see that you access the arrays from inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

use for or while loop e.g.

```
$i = 0; 
while($i < count($ar1) && $i < count($ar2)  ) // $i less than both length ! 
{ 
  $ar1Item = $ar1[$i];
  $ar2Item = $ar2[$i];

  $i++;
}
```

Comment: if you're using a while loop, define the counts beforehand as variables, no need to do the count each loop (same as the post below), use while ($i<$max1 && $i<$max2) and define $max1 = count($ar1) and same for ar2 before the while loop

Answer (score 0):

No to my knowledge with `foreach`, but can be easily done with `for`:

```
<?php

$cond1 = 0<count($array1);
$cond2 = 0<count($array2);

for ($i=0;$cond1 || $cond2;$i++)
{
    if ($cond1)
    {
        // work with $array1
    }
    if ($cond2)
    {
        // work with $array2
    }
    $cond1 = 0<count($array1);
    $cond2 = 0<count($array2);
}

?>
```